# .present? on an ActiveRecord object triggering after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently working on a project in rails and I have two models, **Foo** and **Bar**. Their relation is **Foo** belongs to **Bar**.

### Expected Behavior

Whenever I try to call **.present?**, it shall tell me that specific object is **present or not?** For my given scenario, **Foo.first.bar.present?** shall only tell me if bar **strong text**for for that **foo** is present or not.

### Actual behavior

Calling **Foo.first.bar.present?** is triggering **.save** on **bar** object which is making difficulties for me as there are some callbacks which may take time updating heavy data after saving a specific bar object. Screenshot link available below

https://share.getcloudapp.com/d5u0bykB

### System configuration

Rails version:
**Rails 5.0.7.2**

Ruby version:
**ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-darwin18]**

Comment: Hi, can you also share how the associations between Foo and Bar are defined?

Comment: @AmitBadheka please refer to the screenshot below
https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAuv4JDd

Comment: are you sure it is the after_save callback was called and not after_find or after_initialize callbacks?

Comment: @Fernand yes I am sure.

Comment: paste the code on the question, not pictures (read stack overflow guidelines), also show the relevant code, not just the associations (show the callbacks too for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the source code for [`present?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L25) and [`blank?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L18) that these methods will never save the record. So the cause for your issue has to be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I have been using rails for last couple of years and yes I know they will never save the record, but in my case they are triggering, I am not overriding or anything for these default rails methods, thats why it is weird for me.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't intend to offend you. But I can't see a way how `present?` will save an object. Maybe it's a Gem that monkey patches the Object class? Maybe it's some weird interaction in your code?

Comment: yes you maybe right but I have no idea how to trace back to that monkey patch as the project is not a small one. Let's hope I find it.